# Python: create a list of lists from a file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

File:

```
 1 2,5 3,1
 2 4,10 1,5
 3 4,1 1,1
 4 2,10 3,1
```

I'd like to create dictionary as follows:

```
{1:[[2,5], [3,1]], 2:[[4,10], [1,5]], 
 3: [[4,1], [1,1]], 4: [[2,10], [3,1]]}
```

I managed to achieve this:

```
{1: [['2,5'], ['3,1']], 2: [['4,10'], ['1,5']], 
 3: [['4,1'], ['1,1']], 4: [['2,10'], ['3,1']]}
```

Using the following code:

```
f = open("file.txt")
D = {}

for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split(" ")   
    for i in line:
        D[int(line[0])] = [[x] for x in line[1:]]
print D
```

Comment: So instead of `[x]` you want something like `map(int, x.split(','))`?

Comment: I want dict to look like exactly as the first one containing only integers in lists, just look the example.

Comment: I did *"just look the example"*. So, have you tried what I just suggested?!

Comment: Yes, I am doing it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open("file.txt")
D = {}

for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split(" ")   
    for i in line:
        D[int(line[0])] = [[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in line[1:]]
print D
```

Edit: tested. Should work fine :)

Because your original code contains a list comprehension I'm going to assume you understand them. All I did was turn `[x]` into `[int(y) for y in x.split(',')]`. I.e., `['3,4'] ->[3,4]`.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.